# Debugging Django in VSCode error

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

**I try to debug my Django app in VSCode**

my **launch.json** settings:

```
  {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "pythonPath": "D:\\software\\program_books\\python\\exercises\\mezzanine\\env\\Scripts\\python.exe",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\mezzanine-themes-master\\mezzanine-themes-master\\manage.py",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "args": [
                "runserver",
                "--noreload",
                "--nothreading"          
            ],
            "env": {},
            "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
            "debugOptions": [
                "RedirectOutput",
                "DjangoDebugging"
            ]
        }
```

**cosole error info**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\mezzanine-themes-master\mezzanine-themes-master\manage.py", line 26, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 62, in execute
    super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 101, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "D:\software\program_books\python\exercises\mezzanine\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in run
    self.inner_run(None, **options)
TypeError: inner_run() got multiple values for argument 'show_banner'
```

**Anybody know what my issue could possibly be? I just want to debug my application!**

Comment: Is that all the code that is on the file? Can you post more code?

Comment: I guess the problem has been moved to https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1845

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Unfortunately the Mezzanine developer claims this is not a problem with Mezzanine. I'm dropping Mezzanine, as I like VS Code better.

Comment: Share info about your folder structure